# Difficulties in learning authentication routes in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In authentication in laravel 5.5, it gives automatic user login and registration form. But when I click on login button in login form, It shows the route('login').

I don't know what does this mean. Similarly, in the case of register and other cases too. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Auth::routes` calls the `Router::auth` [method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L1115), which has the following code:

```
/**
* Register the typical authentication routes for an application.
*
* @return void
*/
public function auth()
{
    // Authentication Routes...
    $this->get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
    $this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
    $this->post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
    // Registration Routes...
    $this->get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
    $this->post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
    // Password Reset Routes...
    $this->get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
    $this->post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
    $this->get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
    $this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
}
```

So, as you can see above, the named route `login` refers to the get call to show the login form.